# ADFS Authentication using Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, adfs

Need to have ADFS authentication for Asp.net core web api without WSFoundetion

(angular + Asp.net core)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official Microsoft sample for this but [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/protecting-a-net-core-2-0-spa-with-adfs/ba-p/336730) should get you going.

It uses OpenID Connect not WS-Fed.

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/authenticating-to-active-directory-federation-services-adfs-2019-with-net-core-3-1-b0bf012fc183

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to solve the issue will be to integrate **OAuth** with **ADFS**.

Take a look at **[OAUTH2 Authentication with ADFS 3.0](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/09/OAUTH2-Authentication-with-ADFS-3.0.html)**.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate an ASP.NET Core application with AD FS using SAML 2.0. It can be a good solution depending on you AD FS version. Old AD FS versions do not support OAuth 2.0 or OIDC.

The [ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2) component support AD FS. [ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore/) support ASP.NET Core Full Framwork. Where the [Support-Core-2.1](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/Support-Core-2.1-(net472%3Bnet462%3Bnetcoreapp2.1)) branche support ASP.NET Core 2.1 without framwork.

The TestWebAppCore sample show how to implement SAML 2.0 in a Relying Party (RP).